# Можно ли перенести БД с SDF в Microsoft SQL Server Query File (.sql)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть БД в формате sdf.Можно ли  перенести БД с SDF в Microsoft SQL Server Query File (.sql)? А то не хочется все заново делать(

Comment: *У меня есть БД в формате sdf.* Это что? база MS SQL CE? Mail storage file? что-то ещё? А так - установите CE, подключите базу, экспортируйте в .SQL, и грузите куда надо...

Comment: @Akina MS SQL CE